# Bind error logging syslog

Tags: logs, syslog, bind

Im have this strange behaviour where my bind server is just forwarding info and notice errors to my remote syslog server.

Current configuration on the named.conf file is:

```
logging {
channel syslog
syslog localo;
severity info;
print-severity yes;
print-category yes;
print-time yes;
};
```

Of course that in both rsyslog.conf the line for bind is: local0.*
Nevertheless I'm facing this problem, maybe im missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BIND log configuration is missing one set of curly brackets, and `localo` should be `local0`. You'll also need one or more `category` keywords to send log messages to the custom logging channel you've just defined.

This is what it should look like:

```
logging {
        channel syslog {
                syslog local0;
                severity info;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-time yes;
        };
        category default { syslog; };
        # if there are no other 'category' statements,
        # this will include everything except query logging.
};
```

If you have no `category` statements at all, BIND will only use its built-in default logging channels, one of which is `default_syslog`. It uses the syslog facility `daemon`, so the messages won't match the `local0` facility you're expecting in your `rsyslog.conf` configuration.

You should use `named-checkconf` to check your `named.conf` for syntax errors. See https://bind.isc.org/doc/arm/9.11/man.named-checkconf.html for more information.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I had but still doesnt work. The missing curly brackets were because I copy pasted the text from a screenshot. Sorry about the super beyond answer have been very busy with tons of exams. Anyways, ill give you the correct answer because its supposed to be like that, but somehow it doest work. If I test the facility it forwards correctly nevertheless.